# Mouse click value won't update

Tags: c#, input, xna

i'm making a simple click game, just to get my hands on the mouse input class.

So, i have a button class(which is just a random picture of a cat^^) and a counter class(which counts how many times i've clicked) and the game itself will be a "Cookie Clicker" type of game ;D

But a variable won't update when i use it from another class, even though it's public, here's my classes:

```
class catButton
{
    Texture2D buttonTexture;
    Vector2 buttonPosition;
    public Rectangle buttonRectangle;

    public MouseState currentMouseState;
    public MouseState previousMouseState;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        buttonPosition = new Vector2(150, 300);
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        buttonTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("cat");
        buttonRectangle = new Rectangle((int)buttonPosition.X, (int)buttonPosition.Y, buttonTexture.Width, buttonTexture.Height);    
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        previousMouseState = currentMouseState;
        currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();  
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
            spriteBatch.Draw(buttonTexture, buttonRectangle, Color.White);
    }      
}
```

and my counter:

```
class catCounter
{
    SpriteFont catfont;
    Vector2 counterPosition;

    catButton button = new catButton();


    public MouseState currentMouseState;
    public MouseState previousMouseState;

    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

    public float amountOfCats = 0;

    public catCounter()
    {

    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        counterPosition = new Vector2(205, 155);
        catfont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("counter");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && button.buttonRectangle.Contains(new Point(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y)))
        {
            amountOfCats++;
        }

        previousMouseState = currentMouseState;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(catfont, "Cats: " + amountOfCats, counterPosition, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Should i do the mouse clicks in `Game1.cs` instead?

I had short time writing this sorry, if you have to know anything tell me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't the variable update when you use it from another class?
You must be approaching how to collect this variable incorrectly.

Which variable is it? What particular call should update it, but does not do as intended?

I assume you update and draw the components by first initializing the `catCounter` class into an object in your Game1.cs file, and calling `Update()` and `Draw()` on this object within the relevant methods inside Game1.cs as well, but just mentioning it in case that is what's missing.

Worth noting that the `Update` method of `catButton` is just a waste. Just remove the two lines within it. It does absolutely nothing as you don't re-use those mouse states anywhere. Also in your `catCounter` update, you re-define `currentMouseState` as a local variable within that scope, rendering your `public MouseState currentMouseState` worthless and unused.

Either way, a few things to note about XNA components. Since your classes currently follow the given XNA structure, you should consider inheriting `DrawableGameComponent` for your classes:

```
class catCounter: DrawableGameComponent
```

Allowing you to do:

```
Components.Add(new catCounter());
```

Which will make it so that you do not have to call the `Update()` and `Draw()` methods manually, although you need to override the methods that are specific for it (eg. `Initialize`, `LoadContent`, `Update`, `Draw`).

I am sorry that it is not possible for me to understand where your problem lies when you do not tell us where the problem even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think a better way to do it is if you created a variable called `clicked` and set it to `False`.

Then:

```
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (clicked == False && button.buttonRectangle.Contains(new Point(currentMouseState.X, currentMouseState.Y)))
            {
                amountOfCats++;
                clicked = True;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            clicked = False
        }

        // Not needed - previousMouseState = currentMouseState;
    }
```

**NB:** Dont forget to make clicked a `bool` variable.

This way, you can prevent the user from holding the mouse down, and it does not rely on a second mouse state variable.

As for the reason your code wasn't working, is because the `Mouse.GetState()` is automatically updated. Thus, `previousMouseState` would always be the current mouse state.

I hope this helped.

Mona